# Go /etc/resolv.conf missing in android

Tags: android, go

I cross compiled my Go source code to Arm to run in Android .The program runs in the terminal in the Android device, but I get an error saying that /etc/resolv.conf is missing. My program heavily relies on the net/http library in making http calls.

How can I handle this error in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of right now you can't use the built in net/http to connect to hostnames, check this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8020&q=%2Fetc%2Fresolv.conf&colspec=ID%20Status%20Stars%20Release%20Owner%20Repo%20Summary).

There are few workarounds you could use.

1. generate /etc/resolv.conf on your program start if you have root access, ugly but easy and simple.
2. store resolv.conf somewhere and patch http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/dnsclient_unix.go#L169 to use that custom path.
3. patch `$GOROOT/src/pkg/net/dnsconfig_unix.go` to get the nameservers by executing `getprop net.dns1` and `getprop net.dns2`.
4. implement the full patch at https://gist.github.com/ernesto-jimenez/8042366

Comment: @ShenalSilva I added that, but you will have to patch dnsclient_unix to set the path.

Comment: A quick update, the issue referred to here (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8020) has been fixed and closed in 2016 so Go does now support Android. I don't know whether that means the question now has a simpler valid answer as I'm not actively working in this area.